# Parsing HTTP array response with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, http, parsing

I'm trying to parse HTTP response via json, but it gives me character error, but when I'm trying to loop through this response via for loop, it splits everything in single characters. Is there better way to parse this response?

Code:

```
    _url = self.MAIN_URL
    try:
        _request = self.__webSession.get(_url, cookies=self.__cookies)
        if _request.status_code != 200:
            self.log("Request failed with code: {}. URL: {}".format(_request.status_code, _url))
            return
    except Exception as err:
        self.log("[e4] Web-request error: {}. URL: {}".format(err, _url))
        return

    _text = _request.json()
```

json.loads() returns following

```
 Expecting value: line 1 column 110 (char 109)
```

HTTP Response needed to be parsed:

```
[
  [
    9266939,
    'Value1',
    'Value2',
    'Value3',
            ,
    'Value4',
        [
            [
                'number',
                'number2',
                    [
                        'value',
                               ,
                        'value2'
                    ]
            ]
        ]
  ],
  [
    5987798,
    'Value1',
    'Value2',
            ,
    'Value3',
    'Value4',
        [
            [
                'number',
                'number2',
                    [
                        'value',
                        'value2'
                    ]
            ]
        ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: You can use the json.loads function to get python like objects from your json text string.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: Can't, it returns -  Expecting value: line 1 column 110 (char 109)

Comment: Check your http response in this url: [json check](https://jsonlint.com/);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the error message is confusing because of the line and column numbers, the [JSON format](https://www.json.org/) in any case does not accept single quotes for strings, so the given HTTP response is not in JSON format. You have to use double quotes for strings.

So you have to make the input like this instead (if you are in control of it):

```
[
  [
    9266939,
    "Value1",
    "Value2",
    "Value3",
    "Value4",
    [
        [
        "number",
        "number2",
            [
            "value",
            "value2"
            ]
        ]
...
```

If you are not in control of the HTTP response you are parsing, you could replace all single quotes with double quotes before parsing:

```
http_response_string = (get the HTTP response)
adjusted_http_response_string = http_response_string.replace("'", '"')
data = json.loads(adjusted_http_response_string)
```

But that of course comes with a potential risk of replacing single quotes (or apostrophes) that aren't meant to be string delimiters. It might solve the problem sufficiently, though, working most of the time.

**EDIT:**

Further cleanup as requested in the comments:

```
http_response_string = (get the HTTP response)

# More advanced replacement of ' with ", expecting
# strings to always come after at least four spaces,
# and always end in either comma, colon, or newline.
adjusted_http_response_string = \
    re.sub("(    )'", r'\1"',
    re.sub("'([,:\n])", r'"\1',
    http_response_string))

# Replacing faulty ",  ," with ",".
adjusted_http_response_string = \
    re.sub(",(\s*,)*", ",", 
    adjusted_http_response_string)

data = json.loads(adjusted_http_response_string)
```

Comment: Is there some chance to replace empty values from http_response?

Comment: @ReyCreed You're welcome. :-)  Empty values? Like instead of some JSON you get nothing? Can you come with an example? And what do you want these empty values to be replaced with?

Comment: I edited my topic's http response with empty values, which are given. Everything is parsing pretty much well, but when there are some empty values, it throws me same error when there was single quotes - Expecting value: line 1 column 20 (char 19)

Comment: Ah, the ", ," without anything in between the commas. Well, that's another JSON syntax error. I guess you want it to parse as if there is only one comma? In that case use `adjusted_http_response_string = re.sub(",(\s*,)*", ",", adjusted_http_response_string)` and `import re` earlier. But it's getting a bit long for answering in a comment. Are you in control of the HTTP output? It's not really JSON, and it should be corrected at the place it is generated.

Comment: Nice one, that fixed my next syntax error, but now I have next one, when there are multiple empty values next to each other, empty comma separated value and more empty comma separated value. I'm not controlling HTTP output, that's why this is so nasty.

Comment: My misunderstood, there is syntax error when some values is like 'James O'Brian', the problem is that lastname also have apostrophe in it

Comment: Yes, situations like 'James O'Brian' was what I feared as a risk in the last paragraph. Then it becomes complicated. You will have to find patterns in the formatting; for instance, do all strings start after at least four spaces? And do they always end in either a comma, a colon or a newline? As I don't have the complete dataset I cannot search for those patterns. But if so, `adjusted_http_response_string = http_response_string.replace("'", '"')` should be replaced by `adjusted_http_response_string = re.sub("(    )'", r'\1"', re.sub("'([,:\n])", r'"\1', http_response_string))`.

Comment: They always end with comma, ohh I'm taking too much your time for free, can we talk in another place?

Comment: Yes, you can find contact information on my tiny homepage linked to on my profile. :-)